# List configurable options using custom extension?

Tags: php, configurable-product, simple-product

I've purchased an extension called B2B Order List by Ecomwise and my aim was to create a category just visible to wholesale customers that lists relevant products and gives the user the ability to add multiple variants to their cart without flicking from page to page.
Everything is working however, if I've got a list of 10 products and each product has 3 configurable dropdowns (color, size, material etc), is there any way to list each individual variant so the user could add multiple of that same configurable product to their cart?

Currently it looks like this
[image: Current it looks like this;]

And I'm looking for something like this;
[image: And I'm looking for something like this;]

Looking into the code for the extension it renders a select box for configurable options

Any help would be massively appreciated

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Hi AspiringProgrammer,

Please find below answer to your questions.

In addition to your B2B Orderlist requirement, according to the presented requirements, the list of individual variants can be achieved by listing all of the simple products from each configurable product in a way in where for each simple product can be shown it's attribute values set (Color:red,Size:M etc.)in one row. Each simple product can be shown in one row.

Comment: Sorry I don't really understand your answer - appreciate you responding but are you saying this is something that is available out of the box?